# Evaluate $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^n}{2^{k+1}}$ for any integer $n>1$

Tags: summation, power-series

I know this sum is an integer. But I'm interested whether there is a closed form to this sum.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out the various $n$ correspond to the Bell numbers, which do not have a closed form. See [OEIS A000670](https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C%2013%2C%2075%2C%20&sort=&language=&go=Search) for more.